# how subscription based authentication works in complete offline software?

Tags: database, flutter, windows, offline, subscription

I am building software that is completely offline and runs on user machines (windows) user can download software from my website purchase the plan from a website, and generate a license key.
but as the software is completely offline which means user-specific data will be stored in his/her machine. there will be no central database to store it although as the user purchases it from the website I will have single data of all my users with their subscription information. I don't understand how will i validate the user and it's subscription when user is entering the license key as the software is completely offline.

any idea on how the flow should be?
I am building it in flutter for windows

Comment: Have the license key carry its valid term and sign it with your private key. Your software will then use the embedded public key to verify the license information. Of course, a dedicated pirate can simply modify your license logic and/or change the OS date, but trying to stop those is just a waste of time you can use to improve your software.

Answer (score -1):

You can employ a secure approach by storing essential information in the system's keychain. This storage mechanism ensures a high level of security as it restricts modification and presents challenges for deletion. While deletion is technically feasible, it poses difficulties, and even if achieved, the authentication process becomes unattainable. Furthermore, the stored information is bound to the specific device, rendering it non-transferable to another device. This persistence survives app deletion and subsequent re-installation, providing a robust and persistent means of user authentication.

You can use this package [flutter_keychain](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_keychain)

> Keychain is used for iOS AES encryption is used for Android. AES
> secret key is encrypted with RSA and RSA key is stored in KeyStore